# simple question about a translation

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've found this  term "droit exceptionelle" readind an article by A.Beauville.
He is talking about the blow-up of a point. He sais that $E$  is the droit exceptionnel apparue dans l'eclatement de $Q$.
What does it menan?

Comment: Roughly, "E is the exceptional line appearing in the blow-up of Q."

Comment: Probably *[droite](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droite_(math%C3%A9matiques))* with an *e*

Comment: The French term is *droite exceptionnelle* (‘droite’  is feminine in French) and ‘éclatement’  has an acute accent.